# Custom part properties missing in export Orchard 1.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a problem with the import export module in Orchard 1.6:
I want to export a custom type with a part that has a property in it. The export XML contains data from TitlePart, CommonPart, BodyPart and AutoroutePart, however the data from my own part is not there.

Is there anything I should do like implementing an interface or overriding something on my part so that it is contained within the export XML? What are (if any) the extension points of the export module? I have the source of the module but cannot find it.

The module.txt of the particular export module is:
*Name: Import Export

Path: ImportExport

AntiForgery: enabled

Author: The Orchard Team

Website: http://orchardproject.net

Version: 1.6

OrchardVersion: 1.4

Description: Provides content item data import and export capability.

FeatureDescription: Imports and exports content item data

Category: Content*

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override theExporting/Importing methods in your content part driver. Here is a simple example from the `Orchard.Core.Title.Driver.TitlePartDriver`:

```
protected override void Importing(TitlePart part, ImportContentContext context) {
    var title = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, "Title");
    if (title != null) {
        part.Title = title;
    }
}

protected override void Exporting(TitlePart part, ExportContentContext context) {
    context.Element(part.PartDefinition.Name).SetAttributeValue("Title", part.Title);
}
```

The `ImportExportContext` class provides access to the underlying XML structure used to generate the output document, so if you are used to using System.Xml.Linq, XDocument etc then it will all seem familiar.

There are some other examples of usage in `Orchard.Core.Common.Drivers.CommonPartDriver`, `Orchard.Users.Drivers.UserPartDriver`, and `Orchard.Comments.Drivers.CommentPartDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use reflection:

```cs
        string[] notRequiredExportProperties = new string[] 
            {
                "Record", 
                "ContentItem", 
                "Zones", 
                "Id", 
                "TypeDefinition", 
                "TypePartDefinition",
                "PartDefinition", 
                "Settings", 
                "Fields"
            };

        protected override void Importing(ContactPart part, Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ImportContentContext context)
        {
            var contactRecordType = part.Record.GetType();
            var allProps = contactRecordType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in allProps)
            {
                if (Array.FindIndex(notRequiredExportProperties, i => i == p.Name) > -1)
                    continue;

                var importValue = context.Attribute(part.PartDefinition.Name, p.Name);
                var import = Convert.ChangeType(importValue, p.PropertyType);
                if (p.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum)))
                    continue;
                p.SetValue(part.Record, import, null);
            }
        }

        protected override void Exporting(ContactPart part, Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ExportContentContext context)
        {
            var contactPartType = part.GetType();
            var allProps = contactPartType.GetProperties();
            foreach(PropertyInfo p in allProps)
            {
                if (Array.FindIndex(notRequiredExportProperties, i => i == p.Name) > -1)
                    continue;

                var propVal = p.GetValue(part, null);
                context.Element(part.PartDefinition.Name).SetAttributeValue(p.Name, propVal);
            }
        }
```

You may have to do a bit extra to make it support Enums etc. 
This should probably be in a helper class of some sort.