# Orchard CMS complete site data backup / export

Tags: sql-server, orchardcms

I am running a website on Orchard 1.6. The (shared) hosting company I use is not great and I am looking to move to somewhere new, possibly Azure.

The question is, having chosen to use SQL server 2008, is there a way I can export ALL of my site's data through the admin UI? Otherwise I will need to backup the data from the database to which I only have limited access.

Obviously I would then want to re-import it later on elsewhere.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Import/Export module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.ImportExport).

This will work for a lot of content items (pages, menus, widgets etc). If you have custom content parts, you may need to [add import and export support to your content part drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891326/custom-part-properties-missing-in-export-orchard-1-6).

Comment: I had seen this in the orchard gallery just wasn't sure if it was meant for a complete site backup. I tried it on a fresh Orchard install and everything looks as expected. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your hosting company to make a backup of the database for you or tell you how to do it. It's your data, they have to comply. If only for disaster recovery.

Comment: Yes you're right. Just thinking it's easier not to have to deal with them if I can!