# Orchard 1.8 - exporting custom content types

Tags: export, orchardcms, content-type

I have some custom content types that I need to be able to import and export. All these types are created from modules.

Most of them didn't have a problem at all because I used custom database columns. I found a solution for exporting them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891326/custom-part-properties-missing-in-export-orchard-1-6), and it works perfectly.

I have one that I created from the migration, and added a text field and a boolean field using WithField().

My problem is that when I export, only the metadata gets exported, not the data.

My migration looks like this:

```
public int Create()
    {
         SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("TopDealBundleRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            "TopDealBundle", builder => builder
                .Attachable()
                .WithField("BundleID", f => f.OfType(typeof(TextField).Name)
                    .WithDisplayName("Bundle ID"))
                .WithField("MobileOnly", f => f.OfType(typeof(BooleanField).Name)
                    .WithDisplayName("Mobile only?"))
            );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("TopDealBundle", cfg => cfg
            .Creatable()
            .Draftable()
            .WithPart("TitlePart")
            .WithPart("IdentityPart")
            .WithPart("PublishLaterPart")
            .WithPart("TopDealBundle")
            .WithPart("CommonPart"));

        return 1;
    }
```

And my Model is basically empty (I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I don't know how to declare the TextField, and how to get and set it):

```
public class TopDealBundleRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
}

public class TopDealBundle : ContentPart<TopDealBundle>
{
}
```

My driver doesn't have the Importing/Exporting methods yet, those are the ones I want to add somehow.

Thank you for the help in advance!